# Change drop down value to the right color WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

After some time Googling I now have to ask for help.
What I have: 
When I click on the product image, you can of cause see the price and image changing, but the dropdown value is still the same.

What I want:
Is the dropdown menu to change also.

When I click the black image, i want the dropdown menu to change to black also.

Demo page: [link to page](http://additionagency.io/clinicalinnovation/vare/airex-coronella-200/)

Comment: Show us your efforts?

Comment: Show you my google research effort?? I can't show you the coding effort because I really don't know how to do it.. That's the reality. I've tried to find a snippet for it, because i don't want to use a plugins for this little function

Comment: You're asking for code, so he's asking you to show us code you've tried to use to achieve your intended goal.  Even if you found nothing exact on Google, you should have come across something related.

Comment: I'll try to find something and then come back with some kind of snippet. All other questions i've posted I also did post my effort, this is just very difficult for me.

Comment: You can do one thing,
Assign an event to thumbnail click and check for the the url of that image to match with one of the variations image url (you can fetch that data from the form with class 'variations_form', it has a data-product_variations with all the relevant data in json format) and then change the attribute select boxes to shoe the values of the attributes of this particular variation.

Comment: @Chintan - Now i know what to look after. Thanks